# Mongo DB LDAP Bind without SASL

Tags: mongodb, openldap

I was trying to configure mongoDB Enterprise without SASLauthd.

Based on Mongo Documentation this seems like an option but, I'm missing something.
Most likely in my ldap Bind, I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Here is my configuration file.

```
net:
 bindIpAll: true 
 port: 27018 
security:  
 ldap:
  servers: "adldap.example.com"
  bind:
    queryUser: "mongouser@example.com"
    queryPassword: "password"
    method: "simple"
  userToDNMapping:
    '[
      {
       match: "(.+)",
       ldapQuery: "OU=accounts,OU=Generic,OU=mydir,DC=example,DC=com(uid={0})"
       }
     ]'
  transportSecurity: none
setParameter: 
 authenticationMechanisms: PLAIN 
sharding: 
 configDB: config-server/names
systemLog: 
 verbosity: 0
 destination: file 
 path: /tmp/mongos_token.log
```

Here is  my LDAP user which I'm trying to match on

```
CN=mongouser,OU=accounts,OU=Generic,OU=mydir,DC=example,DC=com
```

This is the log statement

```
hard list from config server :: caused by :: command find requires authentication; will retry after 30s
2019-03-06T17:01:37.777-0500 W SHARDING [replSetDistLockPinger] pinging failed for distributed lock pinger :: caused by :: Unauthorized: command findAndModify requires authentication
2019-03-06T17:01:37.777-0500 I ACCESS   [ShardRegistry] Failed to authenticate in transitionToAuth, falling back to no authentication.
2019-03-06T17:01:38.376-0500 I ASIO     [ShardRegistry] Connecting to configserver1.example.com:40000
2019-03-06T17:01:38.389-0500 I ACCESS   [ShardRegistry] Failed to authenticate in transitionToAuth, falling back to no authentication.
2019-03-06T17:01:39.774-0500 W SHARDING [mongosMain] Error initializing sharding state, sleeping for 2 seconds and trying again :: caused by :: Unauthorized: Error loading clusterID :: caused by :: command find requires authentication
```

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Comment: @NeilLunn this seemed like a hybrid scenario .

Comment: Nothing "hybrid" here. "Configuration of Database Settings" ( the sole content of the question ) has nothing to do with "Programming" at all.